# How does one encode a string to a fixed-length tensor for TPU use?

Tags: tensorflow, google-compute-engine, tpu

I have a tf.string tensor (filename) within my labels that works fine when training with a GPU, but when I train using a TPU I get this error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/tpu/tpu_feed.py", line 494, in generate_dequeue_op
    dtypes=self._tuple_types, shapes=sharded_shapes, name=full_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/tpu/ops/tpu_ops.py", line 241, in infeed_dequeue_tuple
    "{}".format(dtype, list(_SUPPORTED_INFEED_DTYPES)))
TypeError: <dtype: 'string'> is not a supported TPU infeed type. Supported types are: [tf.float32, tf.int32, tf.complex64, tf.int64, tf.bool, tf.bfloat16, tf.uint32]
```

While I don't use this tensor for training, I nevertheless need it read from my TFExamples and propagated through the predict() flow of my Estimator for evaluation purposes.  Thus it appears that I need to somehow convert the tf.string tensor to some numeric type for use with the TPU.

Perhaps I can convert the tf.string tensor to a tensor of tf.int32 UTF-8 codepoints?  I took at look at this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/unicode

which suggests something like:

```
tf.strings.unicode_encode(
    tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(batch_chars_padded, padding=-1),
    output_encoding='UTF-8')
```

However, that doesn't appear to give me a tensor with static shape, which is needed for the TPU.

Overall questions:
 1) Suppose I have a tf.string tensor.  How can I pad that string to a fixed length (say 5,000 chars) and then convert it into a UTF-8 codepoint tensor?  (Perhaps not using  tf.RaggedTensor)
 2) Is there a more general workaround for using tf.strings with the TPU (when they're not used as a feature input).

Answer (score -1):

I tried to reproduce your error with the model used in the [TPU Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/quickstart), found in the GCP documentation.

In the dataset.py file there is a specific function in charge of performing the label transformation:

```
def decode_label(label):
   label = tf.io.decode_raw(label, tf.uint8)  # tf.string -> [tf.uint8]
   label = tf.reshape(label, [])  # label is a scalar
   return tf.cast(label, tf.int32)
```

If you delete the transformation:

```
def decode_label_keep_string(label):    
   label = tf.reshape(label, [])  
   return label
```

You get the same error: "TypeError: dtype: 'string' is not a supported TPU infeed type. Supported types are: [tf.float32, tf.int32, tf.complex64, tf.int64, tf.bool, tf.bfloat16, tf.uint32]"

I suggest you, then, that you use the methods found in the "decode_label" function in order to fix the error.

I hope this works fine!

Comment: Doh! Sorry but this doesn't help.  I can translate string labels to integer labels just fine.  The string in question is a filename / identifier for the training example.  So I need that propagated through.  I tried using python's built-in UTF-8 support to pass UTF codepoints through the the TPU.  That works in the end, but it's very hacky and introduces excessive memory requirements.  I was hoping Tensorflow might have a canonical solution given so many people use it for NLP.

Comment: I checked the method you are trying to use

tf.strings.unicode_encode(
    tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(batch_chars_padded, padding=-1),
    output_encoding='UTF-8')

and it is precisely used to go from int to string "tf.strings.unicode_encode: Converts a vector of code points to an encoded string scalar."

have you tried "tf.strings.unicode_decode(text_utf8,
                          input_encoding='UTF-8')" instead?

"tf.strings.unicode_decode: Converts an encoded string scalar to a vector of code points."

Comment: Tried tf.RaggedTensor and didn't work for me; somehow strings were still getting into the TPU graph.  Is there any open-source code relevant here?  I'm totally unfamiliar with how NLP projects do this.

Comment: Yes, tf.RaggedTensor shouldn't work.

Have you tried "tf.strings.unicode_decode(text_utf8, input_encoding='UTF-8')"?